# Differential equation in inhomogeneous cosmological model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this differential equation:
$$\left(\frac{dR(r,t)}{dt}\right)^2 = \frac{F(r)}{R(r)} + f(r). $$
 This differential equation is occuring in Tolman Bondi Lamatre inhomogeneous cosmological model. I am in need of  step by step solution to this differential equation.

Comment: Is $R$ a function of $r$ or of $t$?

Comment: More over, are r or t independent or dependent?

Comment: @RobertIsrael $R$ is indeed a function of $r,t$. But it still doesn't help. Since we don't know what $F(r),f(r)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no derivative with respect to $r$, we can treat it as constant.
Write the differential equation as $$ \left(\dfrac{dR}{dt}\right)^2 = \dfrac{F}{R} + f$$
Besides the constant solution $R = =F/f$, there are implicit solutions
$$ 2  (t - t_0) f^{3/2} = F \ln\left(\dfrac{2 f^{1/2}}{F + 2 f R + 2 \sqrt{f^2 R^2 +fRF}}\right) + 2 \sqrt{f^2R^2 +fRF}$$
Here the "arbitrary constant" $t_0$ is an arbitrary function of $r$.